# implement dynamic nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
mother_dict=
     {'son_dict':{'Name':'Jason','Age':26},'daughter_dict':{'Name':'Emma','Age':19}}
father_dict={}
father_dict['Child']=mother_dict[son_dict]
```

I need a way to replace father_dict['Child'] with a dictionary from mother_dict based on input.
I've tried deleting the contents of father_dict and replacing them with the contents of mother_dict with `.update()`, but that of course adds the whole dictionary, I've tried using `input()` to ask the user for a child, so if they said 'Jason' it would replace 'Child' with son_dict, but when I got into families with ten or so kids there would need to be ten functions, and if the children's names changed then both the functions and the dictionaries would need to be re-written. I'm hung up on using input to grab a specific dictionary from mother_dict and copying it to father_dict.

Comment: could you show us what you've tried so far and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is being downvoted? If this question already exists somewhere or if there is a problem with my wording I'd like to know so I can write better questions in the future.

Comment: The problem with the question (and the likely reason for downvoting) is that you have not provided us with any information about what you have or have not attempted.  We don't need or want your whole code, we want an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Because *This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.*

Comment: Should your example say `father_dict['Child']=mother_dict['son_dict']`?

Comment: Oh god, there are now two @dano type names in these comments. About to get real confusing up in here.  OP you've provided us with your code, great.  Now please show us what you've tried and what you're getting hung up on

Comment: @Leackah - please **[edit]** your question. DO NOT post your code as comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?

```
choice = ''
mother_dict= {'son_dict':{'Name':'Jason','Age':26},'daughter_dict':{'Name':'Emma','Age':19}}
father_dict = {}
while choice not in mother_dict:
    choice = raw_input('Which dict do you want? ')

father_dict[choice] = mother_dict[choice]
```

This code gets input until the input is valid (it is in `mother_dict`), and then it adds that input to `father_dict`.